# sql query to get latest record for each id

Tags: sql, datetime, max, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have one table. From that I need to get latest "Date" for each "id". I wrote query for One id. But I don't know how to apply for multiple  ids.(I mean for each id)

My query for one id is (say table name is tt):

```
select * from (
   SELECT DISTINCT id ,date FROM tt  
   WHERE Trim(id) ='1000082'
   ORDER BY date desc
) where rownum<=1;
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 15):

If you have just two columns, aggregation is good enough:

```
select id, max(date) max_date
from mytable
group by id
```

If you have more columns and you want the entire row that has the latest date for each id, then one option uses a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.date = (select max(t1.date) from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id)
```

Or you can use window functions, if your database supports them:

```
select *
from (select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) rn from mytable t) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Your first solution max(date) worked perfect for me, I have many record for the same user and I need just the most recent record for each user.